# Count missing values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, count

I have a following table called **Test**:

```
Id                                   | SomeId | Value
-----------------------------------------------------
019D9E52-41D1-45DF-81B6-C7CC484115A7 |   1    |   1
262640CA-65C2-4E30-8654-E187ACA1EEF4 |   1    |   1
53710AFC-4E19-4B1C-B68B-CDB713EC3D62 |   1    |   2
8FF7E77C-D04C-4961-82D9-87C2E5A1A096 |   1    |   2
-----------------------------------------------------
119D9E52-41D1-45DF-81B6-C7CC484115A7 |   2    |   1
762640CA-65C2-4E30-8654-E187ACA1EEF4 |   2    |   1
93710AFC-4E19-4B1C-B68B-CDB713EC3D62 |   2    |   2
4FF7E77C-D04C-4961-82D9-87C2E5A1A096 |   2    |   2
```

And there is a view called **TestView**:

```
SomeId | Value | Description
----------------------------
  1    |   1   |    'One'
  1    |   2   |    'Two'
  1    |   3   |    'Three'
----------------------------
  2    |   1   |    'One'
  2    |   2   |    'Two'
```

These are just pseudo code examples.

I want to count all the values from the **Test** table (for a specific **[SomeId]**), and if value from the **TestView** (with a specific **[SomeId]**) is not in the **Test** table I just want to display 0 as count.

If I wanted to count values `WHERE [Test].[SomeId] = 1`, here's the expected result:

```
Value    | Count
-----------------
 One     |   2
 Two     |   2
 Three   |   0
```

This is my query so far:

```
SELECT
    tv.[Description] AS [Value],
    COUNT(t.[Id]) - COUNT(tv.[Value]) AS [Count]
FROM [TestView] AS tv
LEFT JOIN [Test] AS t ON
    t.[SomeId] = tv.[SomeId]
AND t.[Value] = tv.[Value]
WHERE 
    t.[SomeId] = 1
GROUP BY
    tv.[Description]
```

But this gives me bad result... Anyways, here's the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/152cb1/1)

> EDIT:

This is just an addition to a **Test** table. What is Test table has one more foreign key Id, let's call it **OtherId**. Now when I use the query from the answer I won't get the result I wanted. Here's the modified query:

```
SELECT
    t1.Description AS Value,
    COUNT(t2.Value) AS Count
FROM TestView t1
LEFT JOIN test t2
    ON t1.Value = t2.Value AND t1.SomeId = t2.SomeId
WHERE t1.SomeId = 1
  AND t2.[OtherId] = *something* -- this is the addition
GROUP BY t1.Value, t1.Description
ORDER BY t1.Value;
```

Comment: I've found a partial solution for the edit: I can move the condition into the Test table ON condition. But when I JOIN that other table with [OtherId] and I get some column from that table, it will return NULL where Value doesn't exist in the Test table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    t1.Description AS Value,
    COUNT(t2.Value) AS Count
FROM TestView t1
LEFT JOIN test t2
    ON t1.Value = t2.Value AND t1.SomeId = t2.SomeId
WHERE t1.SomeId = 1
GROUP BY t1.Value, t1.Description
ORDER BY t1.Value;
```

[image]

### Demo

Comment: this counts Values with other [SomeId]s

Comment: @jovanM If you have an additional question, and it is only a very small change from what you posted, then feel free to edit your question.  If it is a big departure, then ask a new question, or maybe comment, if it can be answered quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Below is your Solution

```
SELECT
    tv.[Description] AS [Value],
    COUNT(t.[Id]) AS [Count]
FROM  [TestView]  AS tv 
LEFT OUTER JOIN  [Test] AS t ON tv.SomeId = t.SomeId 
                   AND t.Value = tv.value
                   AND t.[SomeId] = 1 


GROUP BY
    tv.[Description]
```

Comment: You might want to add an `ORDER BY` clause to generate the exact expected output.

Comment: yea, that's the least of a problem :)